# Conditonals incase of Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to print the the emails that are contained in list - `x` with the condition that they are of type - `prospect`. Please tell what will be the correct syntax in this case.

```
s = {'domain': 'truecustomer.com', 'webmail': False, 'result': 5, 'limit': 5, 'offset': 0, 'companyName': 'True Customer Group',


       'emails':

             [{'email': 'john@truecustomer.com', 'type': 'email', 'status': 'verified'},

              {'email': 'jim@truecustomer.com', 'type': 'email', 'status': 'verified'},

              {'email': 'johnl@truecustomer.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Leeman', 'position': 'Co-Founder, Managing Director', 'sourcePage': 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-leeman-bba176'},

              {'email': 'john-leeman@truecustomer.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Leeman', 'position': 'Co-Founder, Managing Director', 'sourcePage': 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-leeman-bba176'},

              {'email': 'j.leeman@truecustomer.com', 'type': 'email', 'status': 'verified'}]}

x = (s['emails']) #It's a list
for item in x: #item is dict
    a = item['type']
    if a = prospect:
        print(email)

Output -  File "output.py", line 20
    if a = prospect:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use `if` (conditional logic) instead of `for` (iterate) in that case..

Comment: Why are you using `for`? You should be using `if` for that.

Comment: the code above is full of errors. It's better to start with Python basics in your case

Comment: The equality comparison operator is ==. And the keys and values in your dictionaries are strings which must be qouted. So, you have to write: "prospect" and "email" and if a=="prospect":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for item in x:
    if item['type'] == 'prospect':
        print('%s\n'%item['email'])
```